# T-SQL to Oracle SQL - Return the query result and and count in the same output

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, database-migration

I have a query in t-sql that I have to change to pl-sql, a part I already did, but I am unable to return the result of this query, along with the amount of values of this query. I need this amount to paginate

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
    Id,
    BarcoId,
    AguaCarregada,
    DieselCarregado,
    DataCadastro
FROM ESTOQUE_EMBARCACAO as e
where e.BarcoId = @barcoId
and e.DataCadastro >= @startDate
and e.DataCadastro <= @endDate
ORDER BY DataCadastro Desc
OFFSET @pageSize * (@pageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY

SELECT count(Id) as Total   
FROM ESTOQUE_EMBARCACAO as e
where e.BarcoId = @barcoId
and e.DataCadastro >= @startDate
and e.DataCadastro <= @endDate
```

Oracle SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    Id,
    BarcoId,
  AguaCarregada,
  DieselCarregado,
  DataCadastro
FROM ESTOQUE_EMBARCACAO esto 
where esto.barcoid = :barcoid
and esto.datacadastro >= :starDate
and esto.datacadastro <= :endDate 
ORDER BY esto.datacadastro
OFFSET :PageSize * (:PageNumber - 1) ROWS FETCH NEXT :PageSize ROWS ONLY";
```

How can I return the counter and query in the same result, as in sql server?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, it would be in logic outside of query. You run query with parameter, read all lines and increment PageNumber on next run. If you really need to count, you can have the counter after your HasNext()/next() calls depending on used driver (ex: JDBC, Golang etc)

Comment: I don't understand this question clearly. Your T-SQL query will never return count along with the result. Are you trying to say you need 2 result set on ORACLE same as SQL SERVER.

Comment: Dear, Please put the current output and what you want to output. that though we understand.